# How to implement product microformats in JSON

Tags: json, microformats

I am trying to figure out how to list the microformats-2 in JSON with the correct tags, and setup http://microformats.org/wiki/h-product.

I would like to implement this in my structured data results.

Is it JSON+LD?

Comment: The JSON is what Microformats parsers generate when parsing the HTML. I don’t think it’s intended to provide this JSON directly. It doesn’t seem to be JSON-LD (e.g., seems to miss a `@context`).

Comment: I agree. I apologize as i am learning about microformats and web development, do you know I could implement this parsed JSON in my website as schema.org implements as JSON+LD?

Comment: You mean if you can specify the Microformats as JSON instead of HTML? As I said, I don’t think it’s intended to be used that way (as it’s not intended, it’s not documented; as it’s not documented, parsers likely have no interest in supporting it; etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Microformats are intended to be specified as HTML.

The "Parsed JSON" (as shown in the wiki) is what Microformats2 parsers may generate when parsing the HTML. It’s the "[canonical JSON representation](http://microformats.org/wiki/JSON)" of Microformats2.

It doesn’t seem to be JSON-LD, as, for example, the `@context` is missing.

Comment: Ok,  now I understand. Thank you for your help.